# OpenCV installation error

Tags: pi-3, opencv

I've followed [this](https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-opencv-python-on-raspberry-pi/) installation guide but on the last part where it says:

> Revert back the swap size to its original value of 100MB by editing the `/etc/dphys-swapfile`. And, restart the service by issuing commands."

I type in:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile restart
```

But it says:

```
no such file or directory
```

But its still in the same place, what should I do?

Comment: You don't need to build opencv yourself any more. Install it from piwheels: https://blog.piwheels.org/new-opencv-builds/

Comment: Well its pretty much done i just need to find out how to fix this problem if not ill try that

Comment: Try rebooting. It will automatically restart when you reboot the pi.

Comment: It worked but when i tried to run a simple process some of the commands won't read such as ```cv2.imshow() or cv2.imread () along with the waitkey()```  everything else works fine but a few necessary likes of code. Is it that i dont have have depencies for them or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the author of that tutorial you have linked hasn't learned that Raspbian uses **systemd** instead of old style **SysV** init system since years. Try to restart the swapfile service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl restart dphys-swapfile.service
```

and check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status dphys-swapfile.service
```